# Docker Hub: how to pass ARG or ENV to docker auto build?

Tags: dockerhub

I have a Dockerfile which pulls the source code from Github each time. The github source url can be different each time.

```
ARG git_url
RUN git clone $git_url
```

For the time being, I bound the project with Dockerhub to auto-build the project upon any code changes. However, it seems that there is no way to configure the parameter in auto-build.

What's the best way to pass the parameter to auto-build each time?